# Automating Unbreakable Linux Network (ULN) registration

Tags: linux, redhat, puppet, yum, automation

To register a RHEL 6.4 machine to the Unbreakable Linux Network (ULN), it is required to launch the `uln_register` command.
This command opens a textual interface, where the user has to input the ULN credentials and select the packages.
Once the registration process is terminated, it is possible to run `yum update`.

I would like to automate the registration process (ideally via Puppet, but other ways are ok too) but it seems that `uln_register` can only work as a textual graphical interface.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ULN tools `uln_register` and `ulnreg_ks` are only symlinks to original RHN tools `rhn_register` and `rhnreg_ks` so they may be used the same way. The main change compared to original RHN is in `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date` configuration file where it is defined Oracle ULN server. The first one provides interactive TUI interface while the second one is noninteractive.

So the answer is to use this simple command ([man rhnreg_ks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rhnreg_ks))

```
ulnreg_ks --activationkey=YOUR_ACTIVATION_KEY
```